# (How to achieve pagination with rest high level client and spring?)or an alternative of elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage()

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having issue migrating from transport client to Rest high-level client.
The following code will not work with RestHighLevelClient which I want to use to get a response of aggregated pages of type Class.

```
elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(searchQuery, Class.class)
```

Any suggestions to achieve the same with other method is also welcomed.

Comment: I have the same doubt. Spring data elasticsearch 3.2.x allows to create  Rest high-level client but my old code does not work using this new client ElasticsearchTemplate)

Comment: In my above code i pass native search query to use .pageable property which grants me the ability to do pagination. i want the same functionality which i cant find in search source builder of rest high level client. any ideas?

Comment: My workaround using restHighLevelClient without Spring data elasticserach consist in this code:

Comment: I have added in Answer below your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My workaround using restHighLevelClient without Spring data elasticsearch consist in this code (this is not the solution but perhaps could be help for your solution):

```
        BoolQueryBuilder criteriaQuerySpecification = getCriteriaQuerySpecification(transactionFilter);

        SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        sourceBuilder.sort(new FieldSortBuilder("operation_created_at").order(SortOrder.DESC));
        sourceBuilder.query(criteriaQuerySpecification);

        SearchRequest searchRequest = generateSearchRequest(totalElementsInt, pageNumberInt, sourceBuilder);
        SearchResponse search = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

        List<OperationDto > operations = Arrays.asList(hits).stream().map(hit -> {
            hit.getSourceAsString();
         // get operation is a method mapping from hit to your dto using  Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = hit.getSourceAsMap();
         OperationDto operation = getOperationDto(hit);

            //convert hit to OperationDto
          return operation;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());


private SearchRequest generateSearchRequest(Integer totalElementsInt, Integer pageNumberInt, SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder) {
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("operation-index").types("operation");
    int  offset = pageNumberInt *totalElementsInt;
    sourceBuilder.from(offset);
    sourceBuilder.size(totalElementsInt);
    sourceBuilder.timeout(new TimeValue(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
    return searchRequest;
}
```

Comment: yes i have tried this and it works perfectly but the issue is i need to mention number of actual hits were there. If i use .from and .size i don't get the hits before the .from parameter. and there is no way of finding if there are hits before .from or not.

Comment: I think you could calculate this information:  long totalHits = search.getHits().totalHits; (you have total hits). search.getHits().getHits();-->(hits of your response). If your offset is for example 6 and your search.getHits().getHits().size>0 you will have 6 documents before.

Comment: the only way i know is to hit the elasticsearch twice or to bring all hits and then show only those which are required. Both of which i want to avoid. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: I'll explain with an example: i search for indexname "name".  i have pagesize value and pagenumber value from client which defines how many hits should be shown at a time and hits of which page should be shown.

Comment: if pageSize=2 and we have hits 4 then there will be 2 pages and if the client demands page 2 the the third and fourth hits should be shown with the total number of hits. The way i need to proceed is to hit the database once and bring only third and fourth hit while also knowing how many hits match my search.

Comment: conditions: 1: hit database once 2: bring only what you need while also knowing number of resuls. this is achievable and implemented by the code i've mentioned in question which only works in transport client.

Comment: Response Object:  hits match your search --->search.getHits().totalHits; (your example would be 4). SearchHit[] hits=search.getHits().getHits(); -->elements 3 and 4 (2 elements of page 2) .

Comment: Ok i'll try this and will get back to you.

Comment: Take care with pageNumberInt!!!!In my case first page is pageNumberInt=0.(first page). @VinitPillai.

Comment: The code worked perfectly thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: searchResult brings back only the page your requested but also has searchResult.getTotal() which gives you the total.

Answer (score 1):

**This worked for me**

```
public Page<T> search(){
           Query query;
            SearchHits<T> t;
            Criteria nameCriteria = new Criteria("name").is(text).and(new 
            Criteria("jsonNode").in(String ...)); //This can be any Aggregator
            query = new CriteriaQuery(nameCriteria).setPageable(paging);
            searchHits = elasticsearchOperations.search(query, T.class);
            return (Page) SearchHitSupport.searchPageFor(searchHits, query.getPageable());;
}
```